# Is it possible to schedule a task only on working days?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to schedule a task only for working days (Monday to Friday)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Create a Task
2. On the Triggers tab, click New...
3. Then click Weekly (see below)
4. Choose the days you want
5. Fill in the rest of your requirements.

[image]

Comment: ah great, didn't even click weekly, thought it means once every week ;-) Thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I'm glad I'm not the only one! lol

Comment: @LeeTaylor can i schedule weekly and in the day only, but not at night like after 6pm?

Comment: You can choose any time you like. Just put the relevant time in the relevant boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Or command for those who do not like GUI or just want to script:

```
schtasks /create /sc weekly /D TUE,THU /st 16:00 /f /RI 60 /du 12:00 /tr "'c:\temp\imdms\l.cmd'" /tn lock_mecoms
```

Result:

> SUCCESS: The scheduled task "lock_mecoms" has successfully been
> created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[supplebee.com](https://supplebee.com)allows you to create monthly events on business days and avoid weekends and public holidays
[image]